# how to search on part of string with Filterrific

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, filterrific

I'm implementing the Filterrific gem for a tournament calendar application.
I took the code from the demo 'Student' application and adapted it to the needs of the tournament calendar application.

I noticed that the search function is searching on the beginning of the search string and not a part of the string.

For example, when I have a tournament called: 'Hamburger Michel 2016', it will find the tournament when I start my search query with 'ham', but when I type 'michel', it will not find the tournament.

I tried to solve this by replacing '*' with '%' in the search scope, like this:

```
terms = terms.map {|e|
  e.gsub('%', '%') + '%').gsub(/%+/, %)
  }
```

But that didn't solve the issue.

Is there a way to search on a part of a string instead of a literal string?

Thanks for your help,

Anthony

Answer (score 1):

Start the search value with `*`. So, if you want to search for anything that contains `michel` use: `*michel`